# assertion failurein [ccsprite rotation] Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I get assertion failure error when try to rotate sprite, i guess. The game sim run well exception sometime this error happen. I don't known why?

and this my Log file:

Assertion failure in -[CCSprite rotation], /Users/SCN/Desktop/Stick-ninja-test/Stick-ninja-test/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:207
2015-03-24 08:39:42.207 Fish-hunt[548:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCNode#rotation. RotationX != RotationY. Don't know which one to return'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02c1b5e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x022678b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02c1b448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x019c2fee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   Fish-hunt                           0x000f4f8c -[CCNode rotation] + 236
    5   Fish-hunt                           0x00084dd5 -[GameLayer update:] + 7621
    6   Fish-hunt                           0x000e46af -[CCScheduler update:] + 447
    7   Fish-hunt                           0x000e4e01 -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene] + 225
    8   Fish-hunt                           0x000e68e4 -[CCDirectorDisplayLink mainLoop:] + 52
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0130db8a _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEv + 48
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0130da46 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 310
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0130df6b _ZN2CA7Display16TimerDisplayLink8callbackEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPv + 123
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd9bd6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 22
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd95bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02bc1628 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02bc0ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02bc08db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0396b9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0396b809 GSEventRun + 104
    19  UIKit                               0x00360d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  Fish-hunt                           0x00099a46 main + 134
    21  Fish-hunt                           0x00002a05 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Would you tell my why? thanks

Comment: reason: 'CCNode#rotation. RotationX != RotationY. Don't know which one to return'

Comment: Yes, i know it. But my code use ccsprite.rotation, so why rotationX != rotationY.

Comment: Finally, i resove it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you got the answer, but you have not mentioned how you resolved it. So I am giving how I resolved the same for other user having the same problem.

If you are using only setRotation() and getRotation(). check the value at some point in setRotation() is invalid like NaN or someother value which is not valid. Cocos2d does not give error while setting but after that when you do getRotation(), it gives the error.

Comment: I don't understand, i only use `setVelocity` , does it matter with get and set rotation?

Comment: Sprite has setRotation and getRotation property inherited from node. Can you tell where are you looking..